# IndexOutOfBoundException using java.util.Vector

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, vector, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem using `java.util.Vector` and `java.util.ArrayList.`
I know the capacity or better how many elements will be saved within the  vector. So i initialized a `java.util.List` using an implementation of it leveraging the constructor `new Vector<?>(int capacity)`.

After the initialisation of the List, I used the method `set(index, value)` but this call results in an `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Which is quite confusing because i set the capacity to a given value using the constructor.

The following code snippet shows the problem:

```
  public void calculateSimple(List<Stock> values, int n) {

    if (n<=0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("N must not be zero or negativ");
    }       

    int max = values.size();

    result = new Vector<Double>(max);

    System.out.println("Size of result "+result.size());

    if (max == 0) {
        result.add(0.0);
    }

    if (max <= n) {
        n = max;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {          
        List<Double> subList = values.subList(max-i-n, max-i);
        result.set(result.size()-i, calculateSimpleValue(subList, n));
    }   
}
```

I know i can solve this problem using simple arrays. I want to ask if there are any bugs within the code or do i have some wrong imaginations about the capacity constructor, concerning the class `Vector` or any other `List` implementation.

UPDATE

The question is:
Is it possible to use any kind of java.util data structur in a hybrid way
(Arrays, Dynamic List (or any other))

Comment: you are not using Vector anywhere

Comment: Now i do. Sry tried it also with ArrayList. Changed the code part

Comment: You cannot update values you never added.

Comment: At PM i think this is the problem. I thought the capacity constructor would work like a resize of the c++ vector class but this seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a list initialied with some values, like 0.0 or nulls, here is a quick way to do it:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(100, value));
```

Comment: Thats it. Thats genious. You are leveraging the Vector(Collection<?>) constructor. Thx,

Answer (score 4):

The `capacity` constructor parameter does not mean that such number of elements will be added to `ArrayList` automatically. It just means the initial size of internal buffer which will be allocated. It can be used if you can estimate in advance how many elements you will have in the list to improve the performance. But you still need to add actual elements to the list. You can do it using the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<max; i++) result.add(0.0);
```

Comment: Ok. yes. But i don't want to add something. I want to set something at special position while the given list could be empty in worst case, without using simple arrays.

Comment: You have an empty list. There are no positions there. Thus you cannot set anything in any position unless you add something to the list before.

Answer (score 1):

From the java.util.Vector.set() method i can see

```
 /**
     * Replaces the element at the specified position in this Vector with the
     * specified element.
     *
     * @param index index of the element to replace
     * @param element element to be stored at the specified position
     * @return the element previously at the specified position
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
     *         ({@code index < 0 || index >= size()})
     * @since 1.2
     */
    public synchronized E set(int index, E element) {
        if (index >= elementCount)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);

        E oldValue = elementData(index);
        elementData[index] = element;
        return oldValue;
    }
```

so when you are using the set method it is possible that your `result.size()-i >= calculateSimpleValue(subList, n)` .Where `elementCount = elementdata.length`  in the constructor when you are instantiating the vector.

Answer (score -1):

In the example above , the point where you have used sublist method,  if max=n then in that case it will result into a negative value, which can also result into an IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: no, it can't because i throw an IllegalArgumentException if n is 0 or negative.

Comment: Your equation is max-i-n , and you have also set n=max which  means max-i-max=-i hence negative.  Isnt it????

Comment: Ok this is a critical case. I have to check that. But it is not the answer that solves my question.

Comment: You got the down vote because of the zero or negative part, But anyway can't vote up anymore. SO doesn'l allow that, Delete your answer. I just voted you up concerning your question "Java Throwing Custom Errors". Thx.

Comment: By the definition of set(int index, E element) ,  it is used to replace an existing element in the vector with a new one.In your case since you haven't initialized or filled up the Vector in the  beginning and on that when you  try to do a set it will naturally give you an IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: yes it does. But pls look at the answers. My thought was that I would have initialized the elements of the Vector already by using the capacity constructor. So the invocation of the set method is still not the cause of the problem, But the problem has been solved when you look at the answers.